# php return json encoded string from function

Tags: php, json, encode

One of my functions is returning json encoded content using:

```
return json_encode($json, true);
```

Now in my code, calling this function I've already tried to use:

```
die(var_dump($result[0]));
die(var_dump($result["user"]));
die(var_dump($result->user));
```

None of this worked.
When I dump the whole content I get returned, this is the output:

```
{"usd":1,"user":10000}
```

Comment: Why not you try `die(var_dump($result));` alone and see what happens?

Comment: Have already tried this too, it's returning: string and the length.

Comment: You do know that `json_encode()`'s return value is a string, right?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the $result variable is the content that is returned from the function.

You cannot access the properties inside that json string, before you decode it again. Therefore you will not be able to use $result["user"] or $result->user as the result contains a json string.

You need to decode it first:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Works, thanks. What to do, so I can use $result->user instead of $result["user"]?

Comment: If you want the result to be an object, you have to decode it typing: $result = json_decode($result); (so without the ,true) then you can say $result->user. However if you want to have the result as an associative array so you can use $result['user'] you have to decode it as I wrote in the answer above.